# JPA map simple String object to Oracle Date type?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have a table in which date column is stores as varchar.
while doing the Object relational mapping (i am using eclipselink) i want to map this string/varchar to Date object in java.

My table is :

```
T_BUSINESS
  TRAN_ID        Number, 
  BUSINESS_DATE  Varchar
```

and I want to select all the rows where business date is between two input dates, here problem is since  BUSINESS_DATE  is varchar i cannot carry out the comparison. I can't modify the table and i don't wanna use the Native sql.

Can anybody tell me how can I do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with eclipselink, but I'm quite suree you'll need to write a [custom data type](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Customizing_the_EclipseLink_Application_%28ELUG%29#Creating_Custom_Data_Types) to transform the varchar in whatever format you store it, to a java.util.Date.

Comment: submit your entity class

Comment: Do ***not*** store dates as VARCHAR. Just don't. You'll save yourself (and your co-workers) a **lot** of trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TypeConverter to map this,

See,

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_typeconverter.htm#CHDHCCJF

Doing comparisons in queries may be more difficult, I think the default date format is yyyy-mm-dd so a varchar comparison may work.  Otherwise you really need a real DATE field on the database.  You could use a database function to convert the varchar to a DATE for comparison, such as using CAST or FUNCTION which EclipseLink support is JPQL.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_cast.htm#cast

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm#func