# How can I use CONVERT() SQL Query into JPA Query?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Transaction.getDataFromDateToDate", 
       query = "SELECT t FROM CustomerTransaction t 
       WHERE t.accID.accID = :accID AND CONVERT(varchar(10),t.tranDate,126) 
       BETWEEN :FromDate AND :ToDate order by t.tranID DESC"),
```

I use `JPA 2.1`, query not run . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no standard way to do that in JPA, but depending on what is your JPA provider, it could be possible. For EclipseLink check this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597411/jpa-map-simple-string-object-to-oracle-date-type).